# Prebuilt Version of PdfKit: "Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pdfkit

I am trying to load a custom font file to use in PdfKit, but I constantly get the error above. I know if I were trying to this in Node.Js, I could fix it wih something like:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
```

`var data = fs.readFileSync(filepathHidden);`

The font doesn't seem to be loading properly how can I fix it?

It was raised in [this issue](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/issues/623) on Github and resolved, but I was unable to get his solution to work for me. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: So in what environment are you running it? NodeJS or inside your browser?

Comment: the pre-built version, in browser in normal JS.

Comment: Ok, then I'm not sure how you would load a NodeJS specific module inside your browser.

Comment: See the link provided in question, the solution at the bottom is in normal JS/Jquery but I am unable to get it to work for me.